# Adding View or Button Link to Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

After a bit of a struggle I've managed to bind my model to a Kendo Grid in my MVC app. What I want to do now is add either a Html.ActionLink or a button at the end of each row so that when clicked it opens a new browser window with the details page for the selected person.

My Grid code is such:

```
@ModelType CDB.GridDetail
@Code

Dim myGridData As IQueryable(Of Person) = Model.GridDetailPersons

    Html.Kendo().Grid(Of Person)(myGridData) _
.Name("Grid") _
.Columns(Sub(c)
             c.Bound(Function(s) s.PersonID)
             c.Bound(Function(s) s.Status)
             c.Bound(Function(s) s.OperationsTeam)
             c.Template(Sub()
                            Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", New With {.id = "PersonID"}, New With {.target = "_blank"})
                        End Sub).Title("View").ClientTemplate("client template")
         End Sub) _
                         .Scrollable() _
                        .Render()
End Code
```

The issue I am having is that I can't find a way to bind the PersonID for the row to the .id of the ActionLink. I have tried Person.PersonID and myGridData.PersonID

The code as it is renders the grid and data but no links... the column is empty.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried Richard's answer but this did not work... returned syntax error.

Following the link he provided and looking at some of the other documentation I did find this which did work...

```
c.Bound(Function(p) p.PersonID).Template(Function(t) @<text>@Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", New With {.id = t.PersonID}, New With {.target = "_blank"})</text>
             End Function).Title("View Details").HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "text-align:center;"})
```

which I used to replace the c.Template(Sub..... line

Comment: I've realised where my approach didn't work: I'm used to using `ClientTemplate` (defines a JS template directly) rather than `Template` (takes Razor markup and translates it to a JS template).

Comment: @Richard No problems... the kendo stuff is great but there is very little help when using it with razor vb syntax and I've tried all the c# to vb (even telerik's) converters and they are no help. You did help in a way as I had't come across the documents that you linked to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The column template is a template, it is processed with Kendo's JS templating language and then used for each displayed row. Ie. you need to write code write a Kendo JS template than will be used to create the content that the browser will render.

In this case, because `Html.ActionLink` doen't validate route parameters is to put the template into the id parameter:

```
Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", New With {.id = "#:PersonId#"}, New With {.target = "_blank"}
```

See Kendo's templates [online](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-template).